# How do I set up AndroidStudio for debugging a Lineage/Cyanogen build via ADB?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, stack-trace

I've got the complete LineageOS-13.0 repo, it builds and everything is fine.
I've got AndroidStudio 2.3 installed. 
ADB command-line through USB cable and Wifi works fine.

- Now how do I open the repo in AndroidStudio so it recognizes source directories and is ready for development?
- From there: how do I start a debugging session through ADB?

*Background:* We are building a los-13 image for the S3 Neo i9301. SystemUI somehow stalls for minutes and blocks the device. I want to find out where it is when it stalls. I.e. get the current call stack (stacktrace).
Since there are more problems like this, setting up AndroidStudio will help a lot, I am sure :)

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, but please leave a comment why you don't like the question.

Answer (score 0):

Working on it, but this helped:

Click *Run - Attach Debugger to Android Process*

Click *Run - Get Thread Dump*